# OsmConvert cannot merge multiple maps

Tags: openstreetmap, osmconvert

I use [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Windows) tool to merge maps. This tool merges 3 maps correctly, however if I merge 16 maps, then I see the following error:

> osmconvert Error: could not get 183500800 bytes of memory

This my command:

```
osmconvert.exe asia/armenia-latest.o5m asia/azerbaijan-latest.o5m 
europe/belarus-latest.o5m asia/kazakhstan-latest.o5m asia/kyrgyzstan-latest.o5m 
europe/moldova-latest.o5m russia-latest.o5m asia/tajikistan-latest.o5m 
asia/uzbekistan-latest.o5m europe/bulgaria-latest.o5m europe/hungary-latest.o5m 
europe/poland-latest.o5m europe/romania-latest.o5m europe/slovakia-latest.o5m 
europe/ukraine-latest.o5m europe/czech-republic-latest.o5m -o=merged.o5m
```

Could you say what am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Memory_Management

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/72068/osmconvert-cannot-merge-multiple-maps

Comment: @barrycarter thanks for your comment! However, I cannot understand what you mean. Please, could you clarify what you mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use options to make osmconvert use less memory and use disk space instead.